# Распределенный запрос

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Доброе время суток, форумчане.
Подскажите, пожалуйста:

- как осуществить распределенный запрос к нескольким БД? (вот например, есть компонент в delphi, ADOConnection1, он соединен у меня с БД, на этой же машине, есть также «TADOQuery», в котором я пишу запрос к таблице в этой БД – с этим понятно.
  **Вопрос**: а если запрос происходит в две таблицы, которые находятся в разных БД, как это реализовать?
- и вообще куда запрос обращается сначала?
- и что (или какой компонент) за это отвечает?

Платформа используется - MySQL.

Спасибо.

Comment: Очевидно же, что нужно выполнять 2 разных запроса одновременно к разным БД. Иначе в чем профит распределенной БД?

Comment: Это я знаю, вот, например, запрос:  

    begin
          SQL.Clear;
          SQL.Add('select * from detail');
          Active:=True;
    end;

который делается к одной БД с таблицей "detail", и мне еще нужно сделать запрос к таблице "provider" в другой БД, например:  

      "SELECT * FROM detail LEFT JOIN provider ON detail.provider_id = provider.id"

Это в одной БД.  
А что позволяет сделать такой запрос **сразу к двум БД**?

Comment: Добавить алиас БД.
Select БД1.*, БД2.* From БД1.detail, БД2.имя таблицы..

Comment: >> Почему "распределенный"?
Нет, в том-то и дело, что БД (для начала) 2 шт. Я занимаюсь распределенной РБД

Comment: Вообще то под распределенной БД подразумевается совокупность различных источников - СУБД  или БД (вне СУБД) и даже отдельных таблиц, например dbf, Excel и т.п. Когда Вы работаете с разными БД в пределах одной СУБД термин "распределенный" не подходит. Я, например, часто использую разные БД (в пределах одной СУБД) просто для того, чтобы при разработке разбить данные на группы. Т.е., например, данные подсистемы "Склад" находятся в отдельной БД, но ответственных лиц я по ID нахожу в БД, "принадлежащей" подсистеме "Кадры"  Работаю, в основном, с MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно договориться о терминологии. Никакой распределённой БД здесь нет.
Здесь есть несколько независимых БД. И есть только два способа выполнить запрос к ним обоим:

1. Объединить их средствами СУБД. Например, обе БД на одном сервере, или Linked Server, или какой-нибудь `OpenRowSet`. В общем, это механизмы СУБД и к Delphi отношения не имеют. Как это сделать в MySQL я не подскажу, очень мало опыта с ним имею.
2. Подключиться из программы к двум разным БД, выполнить нужные запросы и потом творчески переработать результаты. Здесь всё просто - добавить компоненты `TADOConnection` и `TADOQuery` для работы со второй БД.